# UNIX Datagram Socket return data to sender

Tags: python, sockets, unix, udp

There is something i can't get my head arround. I've created a unix datagram socket with:

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.socket.bind(SOCKET_FILE)
```

Later in the code i receive messages written to the socket with

```
data, addr = self.socket.recvfrom(4096)
```

But addr appears to be None all the time. But i need it to send back a response.
How can i achieve writing back to the sender with unix datagram sockets?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You did not show us the client code but I guess the client does not call bind for the socket that is used to send messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose we have a server:

```
# server.py
import os
import socket

SOCKET_FILE = "mysocket-server"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(SOCKET_FILE)
data, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
s.close()
os.unlink(SOCKET_FILE)
print(data, addr)
```

If a client connects and sends a message without binding its own name to the socket, like so:

```
# client.py
import socket

SOCKET_FILE = "mysocket-server"
sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sk.sendto("hello", SOCKET_FILE)
sk.close()
```

then the message will be sent anonymously with no address bound on the client side (i.e., with `addr == None`).  Note that this is different from IP datagram sockets which are automatically bound to a fresh address (i.e., host address and port number) as soon as you send data.

For such anonymous messages over Unix datagram sockets, the client has no assigned address, and there is no mechanism by which the server can send return data to the sender.

The simplest solution is for the client to bind it's own private name to the socket:

```
# client2.py
import os
import socket

SERVER_FILE = "mysocket-server"
CLIENT_FILE = "mysocket-client"

sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sk.bind(CLIENT_FILE)
sk.sendto("hello", SERVER_FILE)
data, addr = sk.recvfrom(4096)
print(data,addr)
sk.close()
os.unlink(CLIENT_FILE)
```

Then, using the following modified server:

```
# server2.py
import os
import socket

SOCKET_FILE = "mysocket-server"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(SOCKET_FILE)

data, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
if addr is not None:
s.sendto("world", addr)
print(data, addr)

s.close()
os.unlink(SOCKET_FILE)
```

you can see that two-way communication is possible.

On Linux, there's an "abstract namespace" extension (see the `unix(7)` manpage) which means the client can also bind to an empty name with `sk.bind("")`, like so:

```
# client3.py
import socket

SERVER_FILE = "mysocket-server"

sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sk.bind("")
sk.sendto("hello", SERVER_FILE)
data, addr = sk.recvfrom(4096)
print(data,addr)
sk.close()
```

This automatically binds the client to a fresh "abstract socket address", which sort of emulates what IP datagram sockets already do.

As an alternative approach, you can use `SOCK_SEQPACKET` in place of `SOCK_DGRAM`.  This automatically constructs a two-way connection (like `SOCK_STREAM`) but preserves the message boundaries (like `SOCK_DATAGRAM`).  Here's a server that accepts connections from clients in a loop, receiving and responding to two packets from each client.

```
# server4.py
import os
import socket

SOCKET_FILE = "mysocket-server"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET)
s.bind(SOCKET_FILE)
s.listen(5)

try:
while True:
    (t, _) = s.accept()
    print(t.recv(4096))
    t.send("sun")
    print(t.recv(4096))
    t.send("moon")
    t.close()
finally:
os.unlink(SOCKET_FILE)
```

The following client demonstrates that the response packets are kept separate:

```
# client4.py
import socket

SERVER_FILE = "mysocket-server"

sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET)
sk.connect(SERVER_FILE)
sk.send("hello")
sk.send("goodbye")
print(sk.recv(4096))
print(sk.recv(4096))
sk.close()
```

Here, `server4.py` isn't a great server design, since a badly behaved client can block, preventing the server from serving any other clients.  A real server might use separate worker threads to keep running in the face of slow clients.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind (to a different socket) on both sides.
A socket isn't automatically created for you, hence the server program doesn't get a name to respond to.

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> sk=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_DGRAM,0)
>>> sk.bind('/tmp/abc')
>>> sk.recvfrom(1024)
('hello', '/tmp/abc1')

>>> from socket import *
>>> sk=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_DGRAM,0)
>>> sk.bind('/tmp/abc1')
>>> sk.sendto('hello','/tmp/abc')
5
```