# Writing an external program to interface with wpa_supplicant

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sockets, wpa-supplicant

I need to interact directly with wpa_supplicant from Python. As I understand it one can connect to wpa_supplicant using Unix sockets and wpa_supplicant control interface (https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html).
I wrote a simple program that sends a PING command:

```
import socket

CTRL_SOCKETS = "/home/victor/Research/wpa_supplicant_python/supplicant_conf"
INTERFACE = "wlx84c9b281aa80"
SOCKETFILE = "{}/{}".format(CTRL_SOCKETS, INTERFACE)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(SOCKETFILE)
s.send(b'PING')
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(repr(data))
```

But when I run it, wpa_supplicant reports an error:

> wlx84c9b281aa80: ctrl_iface sendto failed: 107 - Transport endpoint is not connected

Could someone please provide an example, how you would do a 'scan' and then print 'scan_results'.

Comment: As an aside, why use `while 1:` instead of `while True:` ?

Comment: I usually use ′′′while True′′′, but now used ′′′while 1′′′ for short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the type of socket that wpa_supplicant uses (UNIX datagram) does not provide any way for the server to reply. There are [a few ways to get around that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001053/unix-datagram-socket-return-data-to-sender). wpa_supplicant in particular seems to support replies through a separate socket (found at a path appended at the end of each message).

Weirdly enough, this seems to be a relatively common practice in Linux: [/dev/log seems to work in the same way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/how-can-i-communicate-with-a-unix-domain-socket-via-the-shell-on-debian-squeeze).

Here's a program that does what you asked for:

```
import socket, os
from time import sleep

def sendAndReceive(outmsg, csock, ssock_filename):
  '''Sends outmsg to wpa_supplicant and returns the reply'''

  # the return socket object can be used to send the data
  # as long as the address is provided
  csock.sendto(str.encode(outmsg), ssock_filename)

  (bytes, address) = csock.recvfrom(4096)
  inmsg = bytes.decode('utf-8')

  return inmsg

wpasock_file = '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlp3s0'
retsock_file = '/tmp/return_socket'

if os.path.exists(retsock_file):
  os.remove(retsock_file)
retsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
retsock.bind(retsock_file)

replyToScan = sendAndReceive('SCAN', retsock, wpasock_file)
print(f'SCAN: {replyToScan}')

sleep(5)

replyToScanResults = sendAndReceive('SCAN_RESULTS', retsock, wpasock_file)
print(f'SCAN_RESULTS: {replyToScanResults}')

retsock.close()
os.remove(retsock_file)
```